# Add an external micro SD card for Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero-w-2

I own a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W and a micro sd card reader usually used with arduino. Is it possible to connect them using spi? My sd card reader is the following:
[image: Micro SD card reader]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is the name of break-out board?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.

I used one with an Arduino, but they use SPI and serial transfer so are rather slow compared to the `sdio` on the inbuilt card.

I am unsure if there is inbuilt filesystem support - you would have to try.

There are a number of posts on using external SD Card readers but I haven't looked for years.

There is a dtoverlay which should work (I haven't tried)
`dtoverlay -h sdio` will list "documentation"

It certainly wouldn't hurt to try - you can't damage anything.

In practice I use a USB SD Card reader when I want to mount an external SD Card which is much easier.